# do i put secret env variable in eas.json file too or just in expo secret?

Tags: react-native, expo, environment-variables, eas

i created an react native application with the framework expo. I have a .env file with env variables for my development local build. To publish my app in the google play store, the doc say i have to put the same env variable in eas.json file in production env. But the value of my variable are sensitive datas. The doc say i have to create secret with eas secret:push --scope project --env-file .env. i did it and it worked.

My question is : if i have secret, must i put the env variables in eas.json too or not ?
if yes : can i put eas.json file in .gitignore file or not ? and why ?

i try nothing for now. I have to know first.

Comment: Have the same situation. Did you manage to solve it?